# Java Generic Mapper with Generic Class

Tags: java, class, generics, methods, quarkus

I've been trying for a while to create a mapper that converts 2 objects, i.e. from one object to the other, with specification to the Generic Class. Since I can't find out the type in a static method without specifying the classes, I created a generic class for it, but my problem is that I don't know how to initialize my object to be converted and write the individual variables, or more precisely their content, into the object.

I worked out the following solution using ChatGPT and research, but my problem is that I get a ClassCastException on return when I just use Type. ParameteriziedType doesn't work for me at all, for reasons unknown to me.

```java
public abstract class BaseConverter<TIntoEntity,TFromEntity>{

    public TIntoEntity convert(TFromEntity from){
        try{
            TIntoEntity into = null;
            Class<?> fromClass = from.getClass();
            Class<?> intoClass = (Class<?>)((ParameterizedType) BaseConverter.class.getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

            into = (TIntoEntity) intoClass.getConstructor().newInstance();

            Map<String, Field> fromFields = this.getFieldMap(fromClass.getDeclaredFields());
            Map<String, Field> intoFields = this.getFieldMap(intoClass.getDeclaredFields());
            
            for (Map.Entry<String, Field> entry : fromFields.entrySet()) {
                String fieldName = entry.getKey();

                if (intoFields.containsKey(fieldName)) {
                    Field fromField = entry.getValue();
                    Field intoField = intoFields.get(fieldName);
    
                    fromField.setAccessible(true);
                    intoField.setAccessible(true);
    
                    Object value = fromField.get(from);
                    Object intoValue = intoField.get(into);
                    
                    intoValue = DataTypeConverter.convert(intoValue.getClass(),value);
    
                    if(value != null){
                        intoField.set(into, intoValue);
                    }
                }
            }
            return (TIntoEntity) into;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Map<String, Field> getFieldMap(Field[] fields) {
        Map<String, Field> fieldMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            fieldMap.put(field.getName(), field);
        }
        return fieldMap;
    }
}
```

For calling the method I initialize with the QuarkusFramework (@Inject), the mapper in a resource, and then I use a simple post, with simple class, where names and types are also the same.

```java
@RequestScoped
public class Mapper extends BaseConverter<E2, E1> {
    
}

public class E1{
    public long l;
    public String s;
}
public class E2{
    public long l;
    public String s;
}
```

And also with the Fields I'm not sure if it really works like that, because I don't even think I have the right class for the object, and possibly initiate it wrong. Can someone help me how this should look correct. I sit there already several days on it and just do not understand where the problem lies.

I don't want to install any extensions, but create the mapper with "pure Java".

Comment: `BaseConverter.class.getGenericSuperclass()` would return `Object`, because `BaseConverter` has no explicit `extends`. That's not a generic class. Do you mean `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()`?